# How to access Fabric-ca server remotely?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have set up the fabric-ca-server in a vm. Now it is needed to access the server remotely. So I am looking for the possibilities for such access.

I have tried something like changing the hosts in csr.json file. In that, I specified the ip address of vm. But I need to know actually how to access the server remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the fabric-ca-server port with host in your docker compose, then it can be accessed using exposed port.